# How to change toolbar content programmatically?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am trying to change toolbar content programmatically.

Now toolbar has 1 ActionMenuView and 1 TextView:
[image]

app_bar_transaction.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_transaction"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="#F6F6F6"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

        <android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView
            android:id="@+id/menu_transaction"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#5E5E5E"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            android:gravity="center" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

I want to change content of toolbar to this:
[image]

How I can change content of toolbar programmatically?

Comment: get the layout inside toolbar and change the views programmatically.

Comment: Obviously - using Java in Activity. And for convenience new layout.xml

Answer (score 0):

Add a LinearLayout in side your toolbar like this

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar_transaction"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="#F6F6F6"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

     <LinearLayout
           android:id=@+id/toolbar_item_container
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:orientation="horizontal" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

an then in the Java file access this linearlayout like this

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar_transaction);
LinearLayout layoutToolbar = (LinearLayout)mToolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_item_container);
```

now using this layoutToolbar add or remove any View from it

```
layoutToolbar.addView(); and layoutToolbar.removeView();
```

Comment: Why you need LinearLayout in Toolbar if you can work with toolbar directly?

Answer (score 0):

Find your toolbar using its id, and then get the views inside the toolbar using toolbar.findViewById(R.id.view);

Example;

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); 
ImageView imageInToolbar = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
```